# Uploading file geodatabase to PostgreSQL database schema?

Tags: postgresql, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I'm attempting to load a file gdb to an alternate postgresql database schema.
The process works OK with the following but uploads to the public schema.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=GIS user=postgres password=xxxxxx" "C:\test.gdb
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the manual page http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html makes me think that you must add a layer creation option "schema" or dataset open option "active_schema".

> Layer creation options
>
> SCHEMA: Set name of schema for new table. Using the same layer name in
> different schemas is supported, but not in the public schema and
> others. Note that using the -overwrite option of ogr2ogr and -lco
> SCHEMA= option at the same time will not work, as the ogr2ogr utility
> will not understand that the existing layer must be destroyed in the
> specified schema. Use the -nln option of ogr2ogr instead, or better
> the active_schema connection string. See below example.
>
> Dataset open options
>
> ACTIVE_SCHEMA=string: Active schema

I would have a try with these commands:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=GIS user=postgres password=xxxxxx" "C:\test.gdb -lco schema=my_schema

ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=GIS user=postgres password=xxxxxx" "C:\test.gdb -doo ACTIVE_SCHEMA=my_schema
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add into your connection string the option ACTIVE_SCHEMA=your_schema

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=GIS user=postgres password=xxxxxx ACTIVE_SCHEMA=your_schema" "C:\test.gdb
```

All other options can be found in the driver documentation: http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html