# GDAL/OGR import file GDB to a specific PostgreSQL schema

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I'm trying to import a dataset (file GDB) into a PostgreSQL (16) + PostGIS (3.4) database using GDAL 3.6.3 (released 2023/03/07) without any kind of success:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:${PG_URI}" -doo ACTIVE_SCHEMA=my_schema "${file_gdb}"
Warning 1: -doo ignored when creating the output datasource.
```

also:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:${PG_URI}" -lco SCHEMA=my_schema "${file_gdb}"
Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is
         being appended to.
```

or:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:${PG_URI}" -dsco SCHEMA=my_schema "${file_gdb}"
Warning 6: driver PostgreSQL does not support creation option SCHEMA
```

I also tried to expand the connection parameters one by one (but I truly want to use a URI connection string):

```sh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypassword ACTIVE_SCHEMA=my_schema" "${file_gdb}"
```

This takes time and doesn't raise anything special but it writes tables to the `public` schema.

From here, two tightly related questions:

- do I have to manually create the PostgreSQL schema before using `ogr2ogr`?
- how to specify the target schema (in both cases: it already exists/it doesn't already exist) when importing a dataset such as a file GDB (it can be a GPKG)? By default, the `public` schema is used.

###### Doc:

https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#dataset-open-options
https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

###### Related:

[Uploading file geodatabase to PostgreSQL database schema?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234457/uploading-file-geodatabase-to-postgresql-database-schema)

Comment: `-dsco` cannot work because the driver does not support any datastore creation options https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html. And `-doo` is a dataset open option and does not affect writing. It is not documented that GDAL cannot create a new schema, but if you try, you'll see a message like `ERROR 1: Schema "theschema" does not exist.` Your second command should work but the warning suggests that you have already a table with the same name.

Comment: I guess it would work to define the schema in the `-nln` parameter. For example: `ogr2ogr .... -nln my_schema.my_layername ... my_source`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so according to both BERA and user30184 comments, one must:

1. Be sure a table with the same name doesn't exist already in the database public schema (it was my case because of a prior run of one of the commands I tried).
2. Create the schema manually within PostgreSQL itself because the `ogr2ogr` tool cannot do that:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema
    AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

If the schema doesn't already exist, the following error is raised:

```sh
ERROR 1: ERROR:  schema "my_schema" does not exist
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "my_schema"."building_layer"
```

3. Run the GDAL command with the `-lco` option:

```sh
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:${PG_URI}" -lco SCHEMA=my_schema "${file_gdb}"
```

Comment: GDAL can create a new schema, but not ogr2ogr. Try `ogrinfo -sql "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema" PG....`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the precision!